# Как наполнить массив через VALUE checkbox'a?

Tags: php, массивы, checkbox, foreach

Есть массив ($url_array):

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [http://ukr.net] => TEST
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [http://habrahabr.com] => TEST
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [http://joyreactor.cc] => FUN
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [http://test.com] => TEST
        )

)
```

Есть таблица с checkbox'ами:

```
if (is_array($url_array) && count($url_array)>0) {

    foreach ($url_array as $url) {   

      foreach ($url as $bookmark => $category) {

      echo "<tr><td><a href=\"$bookmark\">".$bookmark."</a></td>";
      echo "<td>".$category."</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name=\"add_me[]\" value=".array_shift($url_array)."></td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 

      }

    }

}
```

ВОПРОС. Как наполнить массив add_me[], что-бы он имел вид:

```
Array (

    [http://ukr.net] => NEWS     

    [http://habrahabr.com] => FUN      

    [http://joyreactor.cc] => FUN

    [http://test.com] => TEST

)
```

Пробовал через array_shift, не получается.. Подскажите, кто знает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете указать любой ключ для `add_me`:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='add_me[" . $bookmark . "]' value='" . $category ."'></td>";
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Всё заработало!

Comment: Если ответ помог - вы можете __принять__ его, нажав на галочку.